# git-p4 migrates perforce "main" branch into git branches as subdirectories (doubled code in git branches)

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

## The Situation

Trying to migrate 1 "main" and 2 branches from perforce to git. After mapping the branches in perforce with specs, I tried a typical migration which resulted in code directory duplication issues.

## The Problem

When running "git p4" (either clone or sync), a duplicate of the master branch code is included with the branches and the branch code is in a directory next to the master. I'd expect to see only the branch code in the git staging area.

### Setup

```
#Perforce Repo Structure
//depot/main/branches/MAINT_01
//depot/main/branches/MAINT_02
//depot/main/branches/mobile

# perforce branch maps
# note: mobile and MAINT_02 are branched (in perforce) from MAINT_01
MAINT_02 -> //depot/main/branches/MAINT_01/... //depot/main/branches/MAINT_02/...
mobile  -> //depot/main/branches/MAINT_01/... //depot/main/branches/mobile/...

# Perforce info
Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2009.2/241896 (2010/04/10)
Client Spec: (need to exclude many branches here)
//depot/main/branches/... //buildmaster-scm01/...
-//depot/main/branches/BranchA/... //buildmaster-scm01/BranchA/...
-//depot/main/branches/BranchB/... //buildmaster-scm01/BranchB/...
-//depot/main/branches/tempBranch/... //buildmaster-scm01/tempBranch/...
-//depot/main/branches/Bar/... //buildmaster-scm01/Bar/...
-//depot/main/branches/Foo/... //buildmaster-scm01/Foo/...
-//depot/main/branches/Cheese/... //buildmaster-scm01/Cheese/...

# Git Info (Linux Box)
 /git/buildmaster/git2 302  % git --version
 git version 1.7.12.rc2
```

### Migration Attempt

Here is how it went...

```
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git 225  % git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /git/buildmaster/git/.git/
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git 226  % git p4 sync --detect-branches --use-client-spec //depot/main/branches@all
Importing revision 20482 (88%)
    Importing new branch branches/MAINT_01

    Resuming with change 20482
Importing revision 21137 (96%)
    Importing new branch branches/mobile

    Resuming with change 21137
Importing revision 21396 (100%)
Updated branches: MAINT_01 MAINT_02 mobile
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git 227  % git checkout -b master p4/branches/MAINT_01
Checking out files: 100% (14923/14923), done.
Already on 'master'
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git 228  % git checkout -b rel_2 p4/branches/MAINT_02
Checking out files: 100% (15142/15142), done.
Switched to a new branch 'rel_2'
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git 229  % git checkout -b mobile p4/branches/mobile
Checking out files: 100% (29960/29960), done.
Switched to a new branch 'mobile'
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git 233  % git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
  agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git2 303  % git branch -a
* master
  mobile
  rel_2
  remotes/p4/branches/MAINT_01
  remotes/p4/branches/MAINT_02
  remotes/p4/branches/mobile
```

### Results

```
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git2 304  % git checkout mobile
Checking out files: 100% (15073/15073), done.
Switched to branch 'mobile'
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git2 305  % ls
MAINT_01  mobile
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git2 306  %
```

Note that MAINT_01 and mobile directories have all the correct history but only the contents of mobile should be seen at this level.

### Expectations

The mobile branch branch should not be including the MAINT_01 directory. mobile is a branch of MAINT_01. This is probably something really simple but I'm not seeing it.
Additionally, checking out master just includes MAINT_01 as root. The contents of MAINT_01 should be the root of the branch.

```
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git2_bak 307  % git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git2_bak 308  % ls
MAINT_01
agvscm01.inq.com /git/buildmaster/git2_bak 309  %
```

Appreciate any help here.

---

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the git-p4 script in release 1.7.12.rc2

Comment: I was able to do a more robust import with a released version. I think that may be my problem. Verifying...

Comment: I just ran into this same issue. See my answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11978694/64313

Answer (score 2):

There is a confirmed bug in git as of 1.7.11 in git-p4 module that mis-maps perforce code to git repo when using ***--use-client-spec*** and the ***--detect-branches*** options together. Snippet from an email response when I reported the issue to git dev team...

> Thank you for the detailed report.  It is a bug in 1.7.12-rc2.
>   This series fixes it, on top of origin/master.
>
> The crux of the matter is that files are mapped into the wrong
>   locations in git when both --use-client-spec and --branch-detection
>   are enabled.
>
> Pete Wyckoff (5):
>
> - git p4 test: move client_view() function to library
> - git p4 test: add broken --use-client-spec --detect-branches tests
> - git p4: set  self.branchPrefixes in initialization
> - git p4: do wildcard decoding in stripRepoPath
> - git p4: make branch detection work with --use-client-spec

```
 git-p4.py                     | 75 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------

 t/lib-git-p4.sh               | 18 ++++++++++

 t/t9801-git-p4-branch.sh      | 77 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

 t/t9809-git-p4-client-view.sh | 17 ----------

 4 files changed, 146 insertions(+), 41 deletions(-)
```

Currently they published 1.7.12rc2. Awaiting the fixed version

Comment: Any way to manually sync those folders into the repo preserving the history?