# How to git-p4 clone from the middle of a perforce repo?

Tags: git, clone, perforce, git-p4

I'd like to clone the second half of my repo. It works correctly using the command:

```
git-p4 clone --detect-branches //depot@all
```

So I want to run something like below, but it does not import the files the same way and eventually fails:

```
git-p4 clone --detect-branches //depot@2000,3000
```

How can I get the second method to work correctly?

**Update**: The output I get right now is that p4 becomes stuck in an infinite loop:

```
current change 32688
trying: earliest  latest 6135ce72f69ce262a6237c98da9ffee652be8b03
Reading pipe: git rev-list --bisect 6135ce72f69ce262a6237c98da9ffee652be8b03
Reading pipe: git cat-file commit 6135ce72f69ce262a6237c98da9ffee652be8b03
```

Comment: Does the second method work without --detect-branches?

Comment: What's the failure message, and what is the difference in the way the files are imported ?

Comment: Just to double-check, I think you should have an @ on both the begin and end ranges: "git-p4 clone --detect-branches //depot@2000,@3000".  Is that a typo in the question, in the command you attempted, or am I just mistaken altogether?

Comment: @TimoGeusch, I believe it works without --detect-branches, but I'm not interested in that mode, since ultimately I want to a select number of branches in my history.

Comment: @Casey, the reason I was asking is because I have run into problems with --detect-branches before. The branch mapping between git and Perforce using git-p4 is a little fragile in my experience. It might be necessary to start the clone before the branches come into existence rather than when the branches already exist.

Comment: @CalebHuitt-cjhuitt I think you are right, i didn't know it required the 2nd @ sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my main problem was that I transposed the starting version number incorrectly.

My client spec:

```
 View:
    //depot/main... //HOST/main...
    //depot/dev... //HOST/dev/...         
    //depot/patch... //HOST/patch...
```

and the command:

```
git p4 clone --verbose --use-client-spec --detect-branches //depot@32668,#head repo
```

Now, the only issue I have is the branches in the repo have the branch name prefixed to the directly tree:

```
main/file1.txt
dev/file1.txt
patch/file1.txt
```

**It works now. I updated my version of git-p4 script (v1.7.12-rc3-4-g91e4bfe) to fix this. I'll try to [push into mainline](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/203910) if I can for anyone else trying to do the same thing**